# Ошибка в указателе

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка:

```
char* pStr="Hello";
*pStr='d';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В указателе нет ошибки. Указатель честно указывает на константные данные, которые, естественно, нельзя поменять. На некоторых компиляторах поменять можно, но возможны разнообразные спецэффекты.

Что же делать?
Все зависит от того, что хочется. Если после прививания строка pStr должна указывать на символ 'd', тогда так

```
char* pStr="Hello"; pStr="d";
```

Если хочется поменять первый символ, тогда так

```
char* pStr=strdup("Hello"); *pStr='d';
//.....
free(pStr);
```

Но в метках стоит с++, а не си. Поэтому, может просто воспользоваться плюсовыми строками? И проще и правильнее.

```
std::string Str = "Hello";
Str[0] = 'd';
```

Comment: Вот это ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, теперь возможности комментариев весьма ограничены (отформатировать код не получаается), поэтому придется написать в ответе
(на мой взгяд это не очень правильно, поскольку данный текст по сути не ответ, а небольшое уточнение к ответу @KoVadim).

Оставаясь в рамках Си (проверял в gcc), еще можно сделать и так:

```
char str[] = "Hello", *pStr = str;
...
*pStr = 'd';
puts(pStr);
```

Успешно напечатает `dello`.

Кстати, обратите внимание -- `sizeof(str)` будет 6. Т.е. при инициализации массива char [] строковой константой, естественно, отводится место и под завершающий строку 0.